# mysql table search for members not in a club

Tags: mysql

I have a table of clubs that can have up to 10 members.  How can I query for clubs to join that I am not currently a member.

I can have up to 10 rows for each club, each one with a different member id.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You should at least provide us with your table structure. We cannot just "know" what your table structure is

Comment: I want to try to see if I can answer this with only the info provided..!

Comment: I would have given examples of anything that I tried, but I was completely stumped and did not know what to try.  I have 1 table with these columns clubname, clubowner, members. So, thank you Gloomy penguin.  Your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter that there can be 10 members per club.  This is just a "business" rule or a logical constraint...

Assuming three tables:

```
Club: Club_ID, Club_Name

Member: Member_ID, Member_Name

Club_Member: Club_Member_ID, Club_ID, Member_ID
```

If your Member_ID is 123, this shows all Clubs you belong in:

```
select member.member_id, member.member_name,
       club.club_id, club.club_name 

from   member 

       join club_member on member.member_id = club_member.club_id

       join club on club_member.club_id = club.club_id

where  member_id = 123;
```

To see the ones you aren't in....

```
Select club.club_id, club.club_name 

from   club

where  club.club_id not in (    
             select club.club_id  
             from   member  
                    join club_member on member.member_id = club_member.club_id 
                    join club on club_member.club_id = club.club_id 
             where  member_id = 123)
```

---

If you truly just have one table like this:

```
Club_Members: Club_ID, Club_Name, Member_ID, Member_Name
```

List of all clubs you belong to:

```
select club_id 
from   club_members 
where  member_id=123
```

List of all clubs you don't belong to:

```
select distinct club_id, club_name
from   club_members 
where  club_id not in (
          select club_id 
          from   club_members 
          where  member_id=123 );
```